# What ~ in isin pandas method means&

Tags: python, pandas

`filtered_df = df[~df.index.isin(df_to_remove)]`

What does this `~` reduction mean?
Found it in answers to the task? Was written by smn smart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~ Operator performs a `not` logical operation bitwise, which means it takes a set of data and negates the condition that you are performing on your dataframe.

In your case, `df.index.isin(df_to_remove)`  will return a certain set of values, like `[True, False, True...]`

With `~` operator, the output would be the logical  negation, `[False, True, False...]` or just the negation of the original condition.